# Need help compiling external github modules (Ti.Facebook)

Tags: android, module, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am trying to download and compile the github version of Ti.Facebook found here: https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.facebook. Specifically I am working on the Android module.

I have currently cloned the repo to my local machine, then used Terminal to enter the project 'android' folder. I then ran 'appc run' (also tried 'appc ti build') but after starting well i get a build error.

Error and version data etc. here: http://pastie.org/10842167

I assume that the error is something to do with my setup, rather than an issue with the repo?

It's quite possible that I have missed a setup step but i can find any information to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run modules directly. Modules have to be build.

You can either import this module in Appcelerator studio and "package" from there or build it from command line with "ant".

**How to Build ti.facebook from command line:**

1. Download or clone repo
2. rename android/build.properties.example to android/build.properties and set the paths in there
3. terminal to the module root and run "ant"

Comment: Thanks Nils, I am trying to build not run, sorry bad choice of words! I can't open in Appcelerator studio because it contains no project files. I guess i could create a new project and copy in all of the relevant files etc but surely thats not what everyone has to do? In regard to ant I think that i read that ant is no longer used and 'appc run' is the command to use... just wondering if i missed anything else

Comment: I just build the module with the steps I edited in above. Can you build the module that way? I believe you have to use ant because "appc run" will actually run something, and this should not be possible with modules... Please also make sure that you have all prerequisites for building an android module: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Module_Quick_Start-section-43289022_AndroidModuleQuickStart-AndroidModulePrerequisites

Comment: Thanks again Nils, I have run through the steps. It took me a while to get the correct paths in the build.properties but when I did so I still receive the same errors as before. I now believe that this is a specific module issue, rather than a generic one! I will accept your answer as correct as my question was a generic one, but if you happen to test on the ti.facebook module it would be good to hear of your progress :-)

Answer (score 0):

Running app and building module is two different thing in Appcelerator Studio. For building module you need to install some additional component in your environment.Like: Ant,Eclipse java developemnt tool, Android development too, gpref, Python. You can find full documentation in the following link.
[Documentation Link](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Android+Module+Quick+Start)